# Disabling back-pedal brake

Tags: brakes, modification, coaster

I have a bike with the so-called back-pedal brake, but since it's for someone who's learning I think that it's more an obstacle than an advantage.

Since the bike also has hand-actioned brakes, can I remove the back-pedal braking effect without replacing the wheel?

Comment: Is there a WIRE activating the brake? Shouldn't the very backpedalling activate the brake, without need of a wire and a lever? Confusing...

Comment: @heltonbiker sorry, actually I still have to receive the bike and I just supposed there was a wire because I waw the lever...I'll correct

Comment: I would think that the coaster brake (or back pedal brake) would be easier for someone new to biking to get the hang of.  They are often found on children's bikes.  I don't see how the coaster brake can be much of an obstacle for the new rider.

Comment: +1 good question, I'd be interested to know how these brakes work. I rode one in Holland last year and it took a bit of getting used to.

Comment: I'd read through this and then *carefully* disassemble the brake. I suspect you will be able to determine how to disable. http://sheldonbrown.com/coaster-brakes.html

Comment: How often (and why?!) are you backpedalling while riding, so that the coaster brake would be an obstacle?

Comment: @Kibbee the obstacle IMO is more related to starting, where you can't put the pedals in the right position for the best "push"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you most likely have is an old-fashioned coaster brake, along with a hand brake.  In reality the coaster brake is probably more "natural" for someone learning -- the hand brake is mostly an affectation designed to make the bike appeal more to boys (of all ages).

But it is possible to disassemble the rear hub and disable the brake in most cases.  There are 3-4 different mechanisms used, so it's impossible to give you detailed instructions, but it would be apparent to anyone with sufficient mechanical aptitude.  (But note that the rear hub, in addition to being very greasy inside, contains lots of little parts, and reassembly requires some skill.)

Comment: OK, I have to ask how hand brakes are an affectation designed to appeal to boys.  That statement just demands substantiation.

Comment: @CareyGregory easier to skid?

Comment: @CareyGregory - I have to agree with you here. Hand brakes are more powerful as well as easier to adjust and maintain than coaster brakes; it's hardly an affectation to improve something.

Comment: I don't buy the skidding argument.  It's much easier to skid a coaster brake bike than hand brakes.  Coaster brakes are easier to put a lot of pressure on, and can accept much more pressure without damage.  Years of experience skidding coaster bikes and snapping several hand brake cables have taught me that.  :-)

Comment: @NeilFein - I can't recall coaster brakes ever needing adjustment.

Comment: @DanielRHicks - Internal hubs are supposed to be maintenance-free, too. Experience has taught me that "maintenance-free" nearly never is.

Comment: @NeilFein - I'm just saying that I can't recall the brakes in an old-style Bendix hub ever wearing out, or even in a New Departure, and they were subjected to enormous abuse when I was a kid.  And they didn't need adjustment at all -- nothing to adjust.

Comment: @DanielRHicks I also remember old, bulky bikes being ridden over and over and over and never having a chain replaced OR a chain-skip... Something must have been lost in the way... :P

Comment: I think the coaster breaks and internal hubs work amazingly and are hassle free right up until they fail.  After that, adjustments or fixing can be a big chore. While cable brakes and gears will require more frequent adjustments, but are easily fixed by anybody with a little mechanical aptitude.

Comment: @heltonbiker you are just right. Child non geared bikes can serve with one chain until the chain is rusted to the end. The chain stretch isn't affecting much it's ride.